# Toon.shader not finding _light var

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, glsl, scenekit

So I'm loading my custom shader in Apple's SceneKit by doing.

```
- (NSDictionary *)celShading {
    NSMutableDictionary *shaders = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    shaders[SCNShaderModifierEntryPointFragment] =
    [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"toon" withExtension:@"shader"]
                             encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                error:NULL];
    return shaders;
}
```

My custom shader is toon.shader

```
vec3 lDir = normalize(vec3(0.1,1.0,1.0));
float dotProduct = dot(_surface.normal,lDir);

_lightingContribution.diffuse += (dotProduct * dotProduct * _light.intensity.rgb);
_lightingContribution.diffuse = floor(_lightingContribution.diffuse * 4.0) / 3.0;

vec3 halfVector = normalize(lDir + _surface.view);

dotProduct = max(0.0, pow(max(0.0, dot(_surface.normal, halfVector)), _surface.shininess));
dotProduct = floor(dotProduct * 3.0) / 3.0;

//_lightingContribution.specular += (dotProduct * _light.intensity.rgb);
_lightingContribution.specular = vec3(0,0,0);
```

And this is the error I'm getting.

```
2015-02-27 12:52:48.164 ShadeTest[4729:499612] SceneKit: error, failed to link program: ERROR: 0:64: Use of undeclared identifier '_light'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `_light` struct is only available at the `SCNShaderModifierEntryPointLightingModel` entry point.

You can take a look at the header file, it's a bit more detailed than the [SCNShadable protocol documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNShadable_Protocol/index.html).